# AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified

Tags: apache, docker, macros

I am using a Mac book pro. I am trying to find out why my localhost is not working. it keep returning this message;

i ran a apachei configation test :

> apachectl configtest

```
H00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

suspect that this error occurred because i used brew to install several versions of php.

i understand that i need to edit my apache config file with this.

i ran following command to find out which apache file is being used:

> apachectl -t -D DUMP_INCLUDES

```
Included configuration files:
  (*) /private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf
    (499) /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-mpm.conf
    (505) /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-autoindex.conf
    (545) /private/etc/apache2/other/php7.conf
AH00557: httpd: apr_sockaddr_info_get() failed for endys-MacBook-Pro.local
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.0.1. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

i also use

> which -a apachectl

this returned:

```
/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

i tried this:

> sudo vi /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf

then added:

```
 ServerName localhost
```

but this returned this message:

```
"/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf" "/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf" E212: Can't open file for writing Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

MORE IMPORTANT ;WHEN I DID THIS DOCKER RUN;

> docker run -it -p 80:80 -p 443:443 nginx

IT returned ;

```
   docker: Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint boring_williams 

(8a5af902bb79be542a04718c6945dd8884ab8cca7e2d28ebf30c319f1aa0a0f5): Error starting userland proxy: Bind for 0.0.0.0:80: unexpected error (Failure EADDRINUSE).
```

So there is a define issue with PORT 80 - localhost

I am now unclear which config file i should change and how i can go about locating it.